# Axios + Vue + Vuex manipulating a basic GET with deeply nested data

Tags: ajax, nested, vue.js, axios, json-api

I am trying to make a basic GET call to an API using JSON API specifications with deeply nested relationship data. I'm experiencing an issue with axios or vue manipulating my data...

Paying attention to **pickup** and **delivery** relationships, the raw data looks like the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "parent",
    "id": "34",
    "attributes": {
      // ...
    },
    "relationships": {
      "r1": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "nextparent",
            "id": "62",
            "attributes": {
              // ..
            },
            "relationships": {
              "pickup": {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "type": "package",
                    "id": 521,
                    "attributes": {
                      // ...
                    }
                  },
                  // ...
                ]
              },
              "delivery": {
                "data": []
              }
            }
          },
          // ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... where **pickup** has an array of objects and **delivery** has an empty array. However, when I try to retrieve the **response** in the callback, **delivery** is an exact copy of **pickup**.

```
var promise = window.axios({
  url: window.baseApi + '/my-object/34',
  method: 'get'
})

promise.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Whenever you run `console.log(response)` in the callback, Vue's observers are applied to the response object, which makes me wonder if this is a Vue issue considering that only the relationships of the first *r1* object experience this.

*Screenshot of log from callback (incorrect):*

[image: Incorrect json response from axios callback with Vue observers]

Additionally, I checked the response from the axios **transformResponse** function and the raw json was correct (without observers). This is only happening in the callback.

*Screenshot of log from transformResponse (correct):*

[image: Valid json response from axios transformResponse]

Will update with fiddle, as soon as I can.

**EDIT:**

The axios function is being called in a vuex action. Here is the code:

```
fetchData ({commit, dispatch}) {
  var promise = window.axios({
    url: window.baseApi + '/my-object/34',
    method: 'get'
  })

  promise
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      commit('toggleProgress', {key: 'fetchingData'})
      commit('setActive', response.data.data)
      dispatch('otherModule/setActiveShipments', response.data.data, {root: true})
      dispatch('history/clear')
    })
    .catch(function () {
      //
    })

  return promise
},
```

Comment: Since there's no sign of Vue anywhere in your example code I can't imagine how Vue would even touch the data, yet you say it has Vue's observers. SO I assume you are leaving something out.

Comment: Apologies. Just edited.

Comment: Thanks, but that actually doesn't change my point. at the point of the log, Vue still hasn't touched the data, it's coming straight from axios. Do you have any interceptors set for axios?

Comment: There are no interceptors. I've tried moving the call to a method on a component and what you're saying is correct, Vue doesn't touch the response in the callback and the data is correct. But this seems to be a different case when the call is in a Vuex action.

Comment: Well, then it's probably important what happens in the action after the `// ...`. I assume you add the data to your state somehow?

Comment: I edited this again. Turns out there is an incorrect usage of Lodash _.merge inside the `otherModule/setActiveShipments` action. Didn't realize it would have any effect in the callback. Thanks for your patience with this, I appreciate it.